# List of tables (in DB2, SQL Server, Informix and Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, db2, ibm-midrange, informix

I need to write code to learn some information about several databases. It will be our customer who will execute code, so I will not be able to tune it "online". 
The databases will be Oracle (9, 10, 11), DB2, AS400 DB2, Informix and MS SQL (2000 and 2008).
 I wrote code that I need for Oracle but I know nothing about the other databases. Could you help me with reproducing it for the other databases?
 Many thanks!

1

```
select owner, count(*) -- number of tables in schemes
  from all_tables
 where owner not in ('SYS', 'SYSTEM', 'SYSMAN') and temporary = 'N'
 group by owner
```

2

```
 select atc.owner, atc.data_type, count(*) --number of tables by schemes and datatypes
      from all_tab_columns atc
     inner join all_tables t
        on t.OWNER = atc.OWNER
       and t.TABLE_NAME = atc.TABLE_NAME
     where atc.owner not in ('SYS', 'SYSTEM', 'SYSMAN')
       and t.temporary = 'N'
     group by atc.owner, atc.data_type
```

3

```
select atcom.owner, count(*) --number of comments by schemes
  from all_tab_comments atcom
   inner join all_tables t
    on t.OWNER = atcom.OWNER
   and t.TABLE_NAME = atcom.TABLE_NAME
 where atcom.comments is not null
 and atcom.owner not in ('SYS', 'SYSTEM', 'SYSMAN')
 group by atcom.owner
```

4

```
 select owner, constraint_type, count(*) --number of constraints by schemes and types
      from all_constraints ac
     where status = 'ENABLED' and owner not in ('SYS', 'SYSTEM', 'SYSMAN')
     group by owner, constraint_type
```

Comment: Check out INFORMATION_SCHEMA.

Comment: What API are you using?  If you support connections to many different databases, it seems highly likely that you are using a cross-platform API to connect to the database.  If this is the case, that API (ODBC, JDBC, OLE DB, ODP.Net, etc.) would provide functions to do this rather than writing SQL specific to each database.

Answer (score 0):

You have some options.

1. With some technologies like ODBC or JDBC you can use its API to read such info. If you use JDBC there is `DatabaseMetaData`:
   http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html
2. You can use schema information given by database by querying it via SQL. I use such queries in my tools that dumps database schema to text files: https://code.activestate.com/recipes/576621-dump-informix-schema-to-text/?in=user-186902 . For Informix qyerying for table names looks like:

   ```
   SELECT tabname
   FROM systables
   WHERE tabtype='T'
   AND tabid >= 100
   AND tabname[1] <> '_'
   ORDER BY tabname
   ```